# Accessing session data in view in Code Igniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, session

Is it possible to access session data inside a view?  I currently have the following function in my authentication controller, and need to access some of the data in session data.

Ideally I need this within some Jquery.

```
private function create_session($user) {
        $session                 = array();
        $session['userid']       = $user->id;
        $session['ipaddress']    = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        $session['lastactivity'] = time();
        $session['sessiondata']  = serialize($user);
        return $session;
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to access session data inside a view or do you want to pass session data to the view? Are you using Codeigniters session class?

Comment: I want to access session data inside a view to run some logic.

Comment: You can access session data in your view like you would anywhere else using the `$_SESSION` variable or `$this->session->userdata('item')` and `$this->session->all_userdata()` in the case of Codeigniter. If you uses codeingniters session, don't forget to load it `$this->load->library('session');` What I don't see in your function above is where you are actually setting the session data to the actual session, you are just making an array to a variable called `$session`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example to pass the session data to the view you would do something like:

```
$data['session_data'] = $this->create_session($user);
//Now pass it to the view
$this->load->view('your-view', $data);
```

Now in your view you can access your session data with the `$session_data` variable like:

```
echo $session_data['ipaddress'];
echo $session_data['userid'];
etc.
```

Is this what you are asking? Or do you mean something else?

I don't quite know what you want when you say:

> Ideally I need this within some Jquery.

Personally I would use Codeigniter built in [session class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html).